# Swift Combine publisher being called infinitely

Tags: swiftui, combine

Having issues figuring out why my function crashes/run indefinitely on the second run.

Function runs as expected on the first run. When i switch screens and do (onAppear) the function runs indefinitely without stopping.

Really confuse on why the logic runs perfectly as expected on first run but then indefinitely on the second run.

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class test: ObservableObject {
static let singleton = test()
private var disposables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
@Published var isNext = false
var logs: [Int] = []

func getfullFunctionHistory() -> AnyPublisher<[Int], Error> {
    Future<[Int], Error> { promise in
        self.$isNext.sink { completion in
            print("completion")
        } receiveValue: { bool in
            if self.logs.isEmpty {
                self.logs = [1,2,3]
            }
                if self.logs.count == 1 {
               print("done")
                    self.logs = []
            }else{
                self.logs = self.logs.dropLast(1)
               self.isNext = true
            }
        }.store(in: &self.disposables)
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
}
```

view below

```
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button {
            test.singleton.getfullFunctionHistory()
        } label: {
            Text("Click me")
        }

    }
    .padding()
}
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
}
}
```

I'm expecting "done" to be printed only once. It prints once on the first click. Then on the second click it prints indefinitely. Second click should also print once and so on...

Comment: You code has a lot of compilation errors, fix them and post code that compiles and is testable.

Comment: You have a publisher which publishes values when `isNext` changes but inside your `sink` you are setting `self.isNext = true` (check the last else condition). This causes an infinite loop. I feel you are over complicating it, seems like a [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info). So first explain what you are trying to achieve.